# Corona audio bug on mac? audio.setMaxVolume( ) not working on mac?

Tags: ios, coronasdk

`audio.setMaxVolume( volume, options )` not working on mac in corona simulator, I haven't tested it on the actual iOS device yet though It works perfectly on `windows` and `Android` device:

```
audio.setMaxVolume( 0, { channel=1 } )
```

Has anyone else encountered such a bug in Corona?

I have tested it on the actual device now `iphone-4S` - and it is working... Still not working in simulator on mac though.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, is the simulator outputting an error to the terminal?

Secondly, the setMaxVolume method returns true on success and false otherwise. So try:

```
local volumeSet = audio.setMaxVolume( 0, { channel=1 } )
print("Volume set? "..tostring(volumeSet))
```

This will let you know if Corona thinks it has worked.

NB: The corona documentation 'gotcha' says there is no max volume for the master volume, which means the device itself can set the volume to whatever the user tells it, but you can limit your app's sounds. [Source](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/setMaxVolume.html)

Comment: Returns "true", but the sound keeps playing.. also Im setting volume on channels..

Comment: Have you tried leaving out the specific channel number, so as to set all channels at once? Maybe for some reason channel 1 is not the channel being used (could be different on a device, but the simulator is sometimes different to the behaviour of a device)

If you haven't already, try:
`audio.setMaxVolume( 0, { channel=0 } )`
Setting channel to 0 applies to all channels

Comment: I need to set volume on specific channels, no the master. I guess most important thing is that it works on the device... still rather annoying bug..

Comment: Channel 0 would be all channels, not just the master - it could be worth a shot. Regarding this, the Corona documentation says "Specify 0 to apply the max volume to all the channels". [source](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/audio/setMaxVolume.html)

Comment: master = all channels :)